# Count identical consecutive letters in an array of words

Tags: python, arrays, string

My goal is to count the duplicate letters in a list. So if I have a list `words = ['capps','bat','hatt']` I'm going to get a counter list that outputs `[1,0,1]`. If the input is `['apple aab','gabb','ppl'] the result should be [2,1,1]`.

My strategy takes this list, convert it to a string and uses the list function to break it up into its individual letters. I can iterate of this array and count the amount of duplicates that I get. Is this the correct way approaching this problem?

```
words = ['apple','gabb','ppl']
words = " ".join(str(x) for x in words)
result = [character for character in words]
counter = 0
tmp = []
for i in range(len(result)-1):
    if result[i] == result[i+1]:
        if result[i] and result[i+1] != ' ':
            counter+=1
        else:
            tmp.append(0)
    tmp.append(counter)

print(tmp)
```

The output I get is `[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3]`.

Comment: So you want a counter of the letters? Why not `collections.Counter(''.join(words))`.  Here that would output `Counter({'a': 2, 'p': 4, 'l': 2, 'e': 1, 'g': 1, 'b': 2})`

Comment: It sounds like you are defining "duplicate" as "two *consecutive* identical letters", rather than the more typical "two or more of a letter in a string", correct?

Comment: I trying to see if the letter ahead of it is the same as the current position. If so then I would add one to counter.@user3483203

Comment: I don't think in a dic if it would allow me to check if the current letter is the same as in postion ahead of it.

Comment: @ggorlen Yes that correct!

Comment: Does 'apppple' count as 1 duplicate, or as 3?

Comment: BTW, `" ".join(str(x) for x in words)` is just a very inefficient way to do `" ".join(words)`.

Comment: @CamiloSalazar I updated the title of your question. Since future users will rely on it to find the question and its answers, try to be as accurate as possible next time. Cheers!

Comment: @pm counts as 1

Answer (score 4):

By *duplicates* you mean that two consecutive characters are identical.

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group identical elements.

### Counting pairs

If what you want is to count the total number of consecutive pairs, by example `'appple'` has *two*, then use the following.

```
from itertools import groupby

words = ['apple aab','gabb','ppl']

counter = []

for word in words:
    counter.append(0)
    for _, group in groupby(word):
        counter[-1] += sum(1 for _ in group) - 1

print(counter) # [2, 1, 1]
```

### Counting sequences

If what you need is to count the number of sequences regardless of their length, by example `'appple'` has only *one* sequence, use this:

```
from itertools import groupby

words = ['apppple aab','gabb','ppl']
#          ^----- one long sequence

counter = []

for word in words:
    counter.append(0)
    for _, group in groupby(word):

        # Here we increment only by one for sequence of length 2 or more
        for word in words:
            if sum(1 for _ in group) > 1:
                counter[-1] += 1

print(counter) # [2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Append operation is quite slow, you can define `counter` with zeros at the start: `counter = [0] * len(words)`.

Comment: Yep, it's O(1) but don't forget about overhead for allocating memory:)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with some functional magic:

```
# counts duplicates in word 
def duplicates(word):
    return sum(1 for x, y in zip(word, word[1:]) if x == y)

result = list(map(duplicates, words))
```

For input `['apple aab','gabb','ppl']` result is `[2,1,1]`.